# How to handle Event in AMP Script

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Does anyone Know how to handle event like (mouse, keyboard events) In amp script??

Actually I have designed a form which has two picklist, Second picklist is dependent on first

When I select the value from first picklist then this value should be passed to the data extension and then second picklist should be populated

How can i do this??

Answer (score 1):

AMPScript is a [Server-side languag](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/index.htm)e, not a client-side language, meaning it cannot be based on User input as it is loaded and compiled before the page/email is displayed.

What you are looking for is likely [javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) to handle this type of user interaction. There are many possible scripts to accomplish what you are asking for inside Javascript or [JQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery).

Comment: Could you please guide me how to use javascript and jquery in landing page with some basic steps ??
I have checked but didn't get any useful information. It's really Urgent.

Comment: Hello @Puja - That is more of a question for Stack Overflow or similar.  Please post your JS question there and make sure to provide samples of what you have tried along with your use case.  SFSE is here for only Salesforce related questions.