# Use Javascript on landing page

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript, landing-page

I am new to marketing could and just want to use Jscript on landing page.

I have searched a lot on Internet but didn't get any useful information

If anyone guide me with some basic steps with any simple code then it will be really helpful..

Thanksss!!!

Comment: Are you using Cloud Pages?

Comment: No, I want to use it on landing page.  someone suggest me to use javascript and jquery for my requirement please see the question at below link for your reference https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/192345/how-to-handle-event-in-amp-script

Comment: Actually, what you're looking for, can be done by AJAX, you need to prepare a separate page for functionality and it should be called on your action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case I'd try to use Javascript within the html page. Basically here is the sample code.

I have seen issues when you try to reference js externally using landing pages and microsites which is why JavaScript within the html file is preferred.

The code in between `<!--` and `-->` is your js code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>

      <script type="text/javascript">
         <!--
            function sayHello() {
               alert("Hello World")
            }
         //-->
      </script>

   </head>

   <body>
      <input type="button" onclick="sayHello()" value="Say Hello" />
   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am using the same code above but not getting output when clicked on the say hello button

Comment: I have added the doc type declaration at the top of the code. could you please try again? Also if you save the code as sample.html and open w your browser it should work.

Comment: @Puja could you also upvote my answer please :). thank you

Comment: Yes I have done. It won't show because I am new to stack exchange and less than 15 reputation

Comment: no worries @Puja

Comment: Have you read my use case whose link i shared in my previous comment. IF you guide me on that question then it will be really helpful

Comment: Yes I saw your issue and you will require good js skills and AMPScript skills to achieve that. Also it is best to debug the code if you have built one. Starting from scratch here is not ideal because user case will be different.